# Use MySQL query result to create chart with FusionCharts

Tags: php, mysql, fusioncharts

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (sl.smsstatus), sl.sms_prefix, sum(sl.parts) AS sum
FROM sms_log sl, sms_transaction st
WHERE
      st.user_id = 552
  AND st.customer_id = 1
  AND st.sendtime >= 1328050800
  AND st.sendtime <= 1328309999
  AND st.sms_trans_id = sl.trans_id
GROUP BY sl.sms_prefix
```

The result as follows:

```
smsstatus | sms_prefix | sum
----------+------------+-----
rejected  |  963       |  2
received  |  971       |  2
```

I want to display this result on Fusion Chart based on country prefix and number of SMS.

This is my code to get the result and display on the chart, But it has a problem, It displays only the first row and $total value comes wrongly=3.

I need to display on the chart ( on XAxis " sms_prefix " and the value is the amount of 'sum').

Thanks and Regards,

```
$res_smsstat_status = $oSMSStatHandlerCnf->get_stat_country($_user_id, $_customer_id, $s_start_time, $s_end_time);

while ($smsstat_status_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_smsstat_status)) {
    $total = $total + $smsstat_status_row['sum'];
    $strXML = "<graph caption='".$oLangHandler->tr("Traffic Graph")."' xAxisName='".$oLangHandler->tr("Delivery Status")."' yAxisName='".$oLangHandler->tr("SMS Amount")."' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0'>";
    if ($total > 0) $strXML .= "<set name='".$smsstat_status_row['sms_prefix']."' value='".$total."' color='#87CEFA'/>";
    $strXML .= "</graph>";
    echo renderChartHTML("chart/FusionCharts/Column2D.swf", "", $strXML, "myNext", 790, 300);
}
```

Comment: remove `DISTINCT` from `DISTINCT (sl.smsstatus)` and add `sl.smsstatus` in `GROUP BY` statement...

Comment: Please use the `JOIN` keyword instead of cartesian joins. Also, do you really want that call to `renderChartHTML()` *inside* your loop?

Comment: So you're saying that the problem is that when you execute the same query directly in MySQL you get the posted result, but when you execute it in PHP, you get a different result from MySQL. Is that right? Are you sure you're connected to the right database? Are you sure that your query is exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have removed `DISTINCT`. Now my query `SELECT sl.sms_prefix, sum( sl.parts ) AS sum FROM sms_log sl, sms_transaction st WHERE st.user_id = 552 AND st.customer_id = 1 AND st.sendtime >= 1328050800 AND st.sendtime <= 1328309999 AND st.sms_trans_id = sl.trans_id GROUP BY sl.sms_prefix ` , and I called `renderChartHTML()` after the loop and It display on the chart only one prefix (971    total=4)

Comment: Yes,(Travesty3) I got correct result but couldn't be displayed correctly on the chart, Something wrong with loop I guess

Comment: Any Help or suggestions?

Comment: FusionCharts shows what you provide in the XML. Something seems to be wrong while you build the XML.

Comment: @alkhader: Is `$total` initialized somewhere else? Try putting `$total = 0;` just before your while-loop. If that doesn't fix it, try adding some debugging output inside your loop, like `echo "total = {$total}, sum = {$smsstat_status_row["sum"]}<br />";` so that you can see more about what's going on. Also, start your reply with '@Travesty3' so that I get a notificiation that you've responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a few corrections in your code:

```
        $res_smsstat_status = $oSMSStatHandlerCnf->get_stat_country($_user_id, $_customer_id, $s_start_time, $s_end_time);

    // Initialize $total to 0 for safe programming

        $total = 0;

    // Initialize $strXML *before* the while loop. If you do this within the loop, then you'll get only 1 chart with all the values summed up.

        $strXML = "<graph caption='".$oLangHandler->tr("Traffic Graph")."' xAxisName='".$oLangHandler->tr("Delivery Status")."' yAxisName='".$oLangHandler->tr("SMS Amount")."' decimalPrecision='0' formatNumberScale='0'>";

        while ($smsstat_status_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_smsstat_status)) {
                $total = $total + $smsstat_status_row['sum'];
                if ($total > 0) $strXML .= "<set name='".$smsstat_status_row['sms_prefix']."' value='".$total."' color='#87CEFA'/>";

        }

        $strXML .= "</graph>";

        echo renderChartHTML("chart/FusionCharts/Column2D.swf", "", $strXML, "myNext", 790, 300);
```